# How to ensure that router.goBack() won't navigate outside of my app domain?

Tags: react-router

In a route component I can access `context.router` and use `.goBack()` method. I want to ensure that it wont navigate outside of my app (to google.com for example) before invoking `.goBack()` method. How I can check if address that `.goBack()` will redirect me to is in my app domain?

Using ReactRouter v2.0.0-rc4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
import { createHistory } from 'history';

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)();

Object.assign(history, {
  goSmartBack: () => {
    if (window.history.length >= 1 && window.history.length <= 2) {
      history.push('/');
    } else {
      history.goBack();
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: How does this guarantee that the previous URL has the same domain of the current one?